# How to get server response time using PHP

Tags: php, server

I needed a script in php that checked for a normal HTTP response from another server like http://www.example.com, a status script to see if the other server(s) where behaving as they should.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Initiate a counter when issuing a request. Stop it when you get the response.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do simply with help of cURL in php. You can send request and view exact time of request.

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET['url']))
  die("enter url");
  $ch = curl_init($_GET['url']); //get url http://www.xxxx.com/cru.php?url=http://www.example.com
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  if(curl_exec($ch))
  {
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to transfer a request to ' . $info['url'];
  }

  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nandu.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have urls you can pass them to this function and you will  get the response time:

```
<?php
// check responsetime for a webbserver
function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    // supress error messages with @
    $file      = @fsockopen($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file){
        $status = -1;  // Site is down
    }
    else{
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }
    return $status;
}
?>
```

> http://tech.fireflake.com/2008/09/17/using-php-to-check-response-time-of-http-server/