# Measure pagespeed "wait" in PHP

Tags: php

I know I could measure the total site loading time for an external url just with something like:

```
$start_request = time();
file_get_contents($url);
$end_request = time ();
$time_taken = $end_request - $start_request;
```

But I don't need the total site loading, I want to measure only the server-response-time like it's displayed here in the "wait"-part of the result:

http://www.bytecheck.com/results?resource=https://www.example.com

How can I do this with php?

Comment: You might want to look at [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) rather than `time()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get server response time using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059737/how-to-get-server-response-time-using-php)

Comment: If you want fine-grained statistics like time to first byte, you'll need to use a lower-level library like [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). The `curl_get_info` function will have what you need.

Comment: @iainn Typo. It's `curl_getinfo()`.

Comment: @CD001 `microtime()` can't help please read the question completely.

Comment: @Webdesigner - fair point, missed the fact that it's an _external_ URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with PHP like so. With `time()` or `microtime()` you can only get the complete time that one or more commands took.

You need a tool where you have access to the **Network Layer Data**. cURL can do this for you, but you have to [enable php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp), it if its not already done.

PHP can than take the result and process it.

> ```
> <?php
> // Create a cURL handle
> $ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');
>
> // Execute
> curl_exec($ch);
>
> // Check if any error occurred
> if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
>   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
>   echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', $info['url'], "\n";
> }
>
> // Close handle
> curl_close($ch);
> ```

You have a bunch of informations in `$info` like

- "filetime"
- "total_time"
- "namelookup_time"
- "connect_time"
- "pretransfer_time"
- "starttransfer_time"
- "redirect_time"

The complete list could be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

The "Wait" time should be the `starttransfer_time` - `pretransfer_time`,
so in your case you need:

```
$wait = $info['starttransfer_time'] - $info['pretransfer_time'];
```